Ngnix returns 504 while processing another request with php-fpm
Here is a simplified version of the page that causes me great trouble:
<?php
passthru('dd if=/path/to/file bs=xx skip=xx count=xx | resource_intensive_command | dd bs=xx skip=xx count=xx');
?>

It only stops when the client stops listening or upon completion (but it is not a quick task). It uses one thread at 100% (+ run dd on other threads).

While processing this request, any other request (needing php-fpm) ends up in a 504 Gateway Time-out error and I would like to know if I can do anything about it. I am running php8.2-fpm and nginx 1.22.1 on Debian (on a Raspberry Pi).
My guess it that it is related to some config but I am completely lost.

I have no idea if it could be an issue but all request load main.php which then calls the correct file.

It turns out that the same session cannot be opened twice simultaneously. (I had session_start() in main.php).
<?php
session_write_close();
passthru('dd if=/path/to/file bs=xx skip=xx count=xx | resource_intensive_command | dd bs=xx skip=xx count=xx');
?>

